# How to add a single quote before each comma

Tags: postgresql

a have a column as below

| mystring |
| --- |
| AC1853551,AC1854125,AC1855220,AC188115,AC1884120,AC1884390,AC1885102 |

I need to transformm it to get this output

| mystring |
| --- |
| ('AC1853551','AC1854125','AC1855220','AC188115','AC1884120','AC1884390','AC1885102') |

Here is my query that i tried

```
select  CONCAT('( , CONCAT (mystring, ')')) from mytablename
```

I'm getting an error when it comes to insert a **single quote '**

Then i thought about replacing the comma with a **','**

How to get desired output

i'm using postgres 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal quote is coded as a doubled quote:

```
select '(''' || replace(mycolumn, ',', ''',''') || ''')'
from mytable
```

See [live demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f4mgSSxT7rMXMm4XPr2zcv/0).